# using the same temporary table from multi php files

Tags: php, mysql, connection

i created a temporary table using a php code , i need to use this table from another php files or or when using multi ajax request i want to get this temporary table always ( not each time i send a request then it will create a new temporary table)

i tried to use the same connection , but it works only on tables that exists in DB and not a temporary table .

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Coverage2/DataModel.php',
    data: {
        source1: document.getElementById(row + "_Query").textContent,
        source2: "loadCoverageTable"
    },
    success: function (data) {
         var queryResult = data;
}
```

i send this request many time and i need in every request to get the same temporary table .

Comment: MySQL temporary tables are destroyed when you close the connection, or the PHP script that created them finishes

Answer (score 1):

A temporary mysql table will only persist as long as the session persists. You might try a persistent connection if you're not already doing so. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php